# Cupon de descuento en PrestaShop

Tags: web, prestashop

Trato de crear una caja en la que el usuario introduce su email y le llega al correo electrónico su cupón de descuento. En caso de que ya lo haya recibido, no se le envía y le da un mensaje de error. No busco que me den la solución mascada, pero si me gustaría que, si alguien conoce algún plugin con el que hacerlo, me lo dijese. O bien, qué archivos tendría que modificar para crear algo así y en qué lenguaje

Comment: Prestashop está programado en **PHP** y para hacer lo que necesitas también deberías usar **Javascript**. Pero si no sabes lo que debes usar me parece poco probable que te sirva de algo el que se te indique que archivo debes editar. Te recomiendo que trates de desarrollar una aplicación similar fuera de Prestashop y cuando lo consigas ya te metas en como se hace en Prestashop.

Comment: Se hacerlo perfectamente en PHP. Y en concreto, creo recordar que Prestashop no funciona con PHP puro, sino con Symphony. Lo que quiero es que me indiquen lo que he pedido, que es lo que no se hacer. Cansa un poco que siempre que se pregunte por aquí te traten de novato (que por cierto, soy un programador web recién salido de la escuela al que me meten prisa con proyectos y de ahí que intente respaldarme en una comunidad con más experiencia). Gracias.

Comment: Symphony es un framework de PHP, por lo que está programado en PHP. Si estás cansado de que se te trate como un "novato", deberías de detallar más tu pregunta, aportando lo que lleves hecho. La pregunta que has planteado no cumple con el tipo de pregunta que es bien aceptada por la comunidad, ya que esta se ocupa de ayudar con problemas puntuales sobre un código dado.

Comment: En vista de tus diversas preguntas sobre prestashop y wordpress te recomiendo que busques y hagas algunos cursos de los principales CMS, Wordpress, Drupal 8, Joomla, PrestaShop y Magento. En cuanto a lo que pides, copia la base de cualquier módulo y haz que llame a tu archivo con una función y devuelva los valores, si ha de devolver algo. En esta web https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/ podrás ver la estructura básica, monta eso, y llama tu función cuando se llame al módulo. Creo que es relativamente sencillo. Algo similar ando haciendo en Drupal 8 y funciona. Suerte.